# data.table warning - Item is of size but maximum size is (recycled leaving a remainder of items)

Tags: r, data.table

I am using data.table J to do subsets of `th1` on 5 columns: `split1, market, dept_size, bool_3, cust_poor_rich`.

I understand I should use `unique(column_name)` to specify that any value should be included for that column.

Though I am running into the following warning with this command:

```
setkey(th1, split1, market, dept_size, bool_3, cust_poor_rich)

subs = th1[J(0, unique(market), unique(dept_size), 1, factor(1)), nomatch=0]
 Warning message:
 In as.data.table.list(i) :
  Item 3 is of size 5 but maximum size is 34 (recycled leaving a remainder of 4 items)
```

I tried to reproduce the error with a small example, but cannot reproduce.

I suppose `Item 3` refers to the third input in J(), and I can see that `length(unique(th1$dept_size))` is 5.

But where does the `34` comes from ?
 and why leaving a remainder of 4 items?

Comment: I bet `length(unique(market))` is 34 (and `34%%5==4`). Why don't you just use `setkey` without market and dept_size, then you could easily do the join.

Comment: @shadow yes, length(unique(market)) is 34. I don't want to setkey without market because I am in a loop and sometimes I do need to binary search using the market value. Same for dept_size.

Answer (score 7):

You could use `CJ` to get all unique combinations instead of all unique values.

```
th1[CJ(0, unique(market), unique(dept_size), 1, factor(1)), nomatch=0]
```

Comment: That would return combinations that are not present in the data; though I want to count the actual data combinations.

Comment: But you use `nomatch=0`, so it doesn't return combinations that are not present in the data.

Comment: Note: `CJ` is a faster `data.table` alternative to `expand.grid`