# R: generate a sequence of graphs (scale-free networks)

Tags: r, igraph

I'm generating a sequence of scale-free networks, in which I can add and remove edges according to a value sampled from a uniform distribution. The following code works, but throws a warning once in awhile (every 10 runs or so). The warning is:

```
Warning message:
In data.table::data.table(...) :
  Item 1 is of size 64 but maximum size is 66 (recycled leaving remainder of 2 items)
```

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23760455/data-table-warning-item-is-of-size-but-maximum-size-is-recycled-leaving-a-rem), but I don't really understand the answer and if it applies in my situation.

The code is:

```
library(igraph)

create_graph_sequence = function(num_nodes, num_timesteps) {

    keep_graphs <- vector(mode="list", length=num_timesteps)
    proportions = runif(2)
    cat('proportions are: ', proportions)
    prop_add = proportions[1] #Let both follow a uniform distribution
    prop_del= proportions[2] 

    min_num_edges = ceiling(num_nodes/2)

    g <- barabasi.game(num_nodes, power=1.2, directed=TRUE, algorithm="psumtree")
    keep_graphs[[1]] = g

    for(i in 2:num_timesteps) {
        print(i)
        edgelist = get.edgelist(keep_graphs[[i-1]]) #(g)

        #Add and remove edges per time step.

        add_edge_to_graph = function() {
            #Do not allow creation of loops! If farm a ships to farm b, then farm b cannot ship to farm a.
            #Do not allow self-loops! If farm a is in the network, it cannot ship to farm a.
            reverse_edgelist = cbind(edgelist[,2], edgelist[,1])
            self_edgelist = cbind(seq(1:num_nodes), seq(1:num_nodes))
            total_edges_not_to_repeat = rbind(edgelist, reverse_edgelist, self_edgelist)

            #Find two nodes that are not in the current edgelist.
            #1: get a (num_nodes)*2 matrix of possible edges
            possible_edges_1 = rep(seq(1:num_nodes), each=num_nodes)
            possible_edges_2 = rep(seq(1:num_nodes), num_nodes)
            possible_edges = cbind(possible_edges_1, possible_edges_2)
            possible_edges = data.matrix(possible_edges)

            DT1 <- data.table(possible_edges)
            DT2 <- data.table(cbind(total_edges_not_to_repeat, 0), key=paste0("V", seq(len=ncol(total_edges_not_to_repeat))))
            setnames(DT2, c(head(names(DT2), -1L), 'found'))
            da <- DT2[DT1, list(found=ifelse(is.na(found), 0, 1))]

            #Append found to the possible_edges
            dt1 <- cbind(DT1, da)

            #randomly select *prop_add* rows that have '0' in the found column and add the edges
            dt1 = data.matrix(dt1)
            select_0 = dt1[dt1[, "found"]==0,]
            new_edge_row = sample(nrow(select_0), ceiling(nrow(edgelist)*prop_add))
            new_edges = select_0[new_edge_row, 1:2] #possible_edges[new_edge_row,]

            #While not all new_edges fit the bill: are self-loops, create loops with other farms, etc.
            #take a new sample.

            new_edges_df = as.data.frame(new_edges, by_row=False)
            tentr_df = as.data.frame(total_edges_not_to_repeat, by_row=True)

            while(any(do.call(paste0,new_edges_df) %in% do.call(paste0, tentr_df))) {
                new_edge_row = sample(nrow(select_0), ceiling(nrow(edgelist)*prop_add))
                new_edges = select_0[new_edge_row, 1:2]
                new_edges_df = as.data.frame(new_edges)
                tentr_df = as.data.frame(total_edges_not_to_repeat)
            }

            new_edges = t(as.matrix(new_edges_df)) #for some reason matrix -> df -> matrix transposes. Transposing back.
            #g2 = g
            print('i-1 is')
            print(i-1)
            #print(keep_graphs[[i-1]])
            g2 = keep_graphs[[i-1]]

            for(i in 1:nrow(new_edges)) {
                addthisedge = c(new_edges[i,][[1]], new_edges[i,][[2]])
                g2 = add_edges(g2, edges = addthisedge)
            }
        return(g2)
        }

        delete_edge_from_graph = function() {
            #Randomly select a second proportion *prop_del* rows to delete 
            #(include the edges from the new graph - this means the number of edges DOES NOT remain constant; 
            #if prop_add = prop_del then yes, stays constant; 
            #if prop_del > prop_add then going to have a graph that gets smaller over time.)
            #BUT if the number to remove results in a graph with unacceptably few edges, then remove no edges.

            g2_edgelist = get.edgelist(g2)
            edges_to_remove = sample(nrow(g2_edgelist), floor(nrow(g2_edgelist)*prop_del)) 
            edgefunctiong2 = E(g2)
            if(nrow(g2_edgelist) - length(edgefunctiong2[edges_to_remove]) < min_num_edges) {
                print('g2')
                print(g2)
                return(g2)
            } else {
            g2 = g2 - edgefunctiong2[edges_to_remove]
            print('g2')
            print(g2)
            return(g2)
            }
        }

        g2 = add_edge_to_graph()
        g2 = delete_edge_from_graph()
        keep_graphs[[i]] = g2
    }
    return(keep_graphs)
}
```

You can call this MWE by:

```
kept_graphs = create_graph_sequence(8, 3)
```

To create a sequence of 3 graphs with 8 nodes. It shouldn't take more than a few seconds to run on a basic laptop.

How can I get rid of this warning message?

Comment: Have you tried `debug()`-ing your function? Run `debug(kept_graphs)` and then keep calling and stepping through it until you get the warning. That should give you a good hint of the exact problem point, and is probably what anyone trying to answer this question is going to do first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the line

```
dt1 <- cbind(DT1, da)
```

It sometimes happens that `DT1` has 64 rows, while `da` has 66. That needs a warning because it doesn't look like a typical recycling (e.g., when one vector is (1,2,3,4,5,6) and we give another (2,3) expecting recycling to make it (2,3,2,3,2,3)).

Since it's not obvious what the function does, I'm sure it's better if you fix the issue yourself. To replicate it, do `set.seed(123)` before calling the function, and add `if(i == 3) browser()` right before `dt1 <- cbind(DT1, da)`.

Comment: Thanks. Turns out there were several errors in that code that were only generated intermittently, which made them really hard to diagnose.